# How does one solve $(x+1)y'+xy^2=0$ subject to $y(0) = 1$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I would like to solve the differential equation
$$(x+1)y'+xy^2=0$$
and initial condition
$$y(0)=1.$$
My result is
$$y=\frac{1}{x-\ln|x+1|+c},$$
while the result from Wolfram is
$$y=\frac{1}{x-\ln(x+1)+c}.$$
For initial condition
$$y=\frac{1}{x-\ln|x+1|+1}$$
I do not know which interval as a domain to choose from $(-\infty,-W(1)-1)$, $(-W(1)-1,-1)$, $(-1,\infty)$. It is my result for condition: $(x-\ln|x+1|+1\neq0) \wedge (x+1\neq0)$. I wonder where did Wolfram get that result without absolute value, is there any trick for it?

And also what solution would it be for initial condition $y(0)=0$, will it be singular solution $y=0$ for $x\in R$?

Comment: Should that be $y'$ instead of $x'$?

Comment: you are right, edited :)

Comment: This is the danger of asking more than one question and not itemizing them. It seems that everyone forgot the last question — what happens when $y(0) = 0$.

Comment: Does anybody know the answer for the last question?

Comment: Have you tried using Picard-Lindelöf?

Comment: I wonder that it can be singular solution $y=0$ for $x\in R$. But I still do not know if domain of that singular solutin $y=0$ is $R$ or $R$\{0}

Comment: You can remove that 2nd question from the question and ask a *new* question. Link to this one.

Answer (score 3):

The real question is whether an antiderivative of $1/x$ should be written as $\ln(x)+c$ or $\ln|x|+c$.  Calculus courses prefer $\ln|x|+c$: that's ok if you 
restrict yourself to real numbers, but doesn't work when complex numbers
are allowed. When complex numbers are allowed, $\ln(x)+ c$ works, as (depending on choice of branch of ln), $\ln(-x) = \ln(x) \pm \pi i$, while $\ln |x|+c$ does not ($\ln|z|$ is not differentiable in the complex sense).  Wolfram doesn't know you
only care about real numbers.

Comment: Thx for reply, but still I do not know what I have to do. I found c from initial condition(c=1) and have to find domain. My suggestion is above.

Comment: In fact the solution should write $\log(-x)+c'\text{ and }\log(x)+c''$, because the constants can differ on both sides of the singularity.

Answer (score 3):

Due to the factor $x+1$, the equation has a singularity and there are two independent branches, on either sides. But as you specify the condition $y(0)$, it is implicit that you consider the branch $x\ge-1$.

Comment: How do you mean two branches? I have three of them.

Comment: @naruto25: I said due to the factor $x+1$.

Comment: So if $x_0\in(-1,\infty)$, then the equation is $\frac{1}{x-ln(x+1)+c}$ and if $x_0\in(-\infty,-1)$, then the equation is $\frac{1}{x-ln(-x-1)+c}$ ? Is it correct?